# content is not defined in node js when i router get home page ' / '

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs, router

content is not defined  in node js when i router get home page ' / '

[image]

**Here i will show you my router page name page.js **

```
router.get('/',function(req,res){
    Page.findOne({slug:'home'},function(err,pages){
        if(err)
            console.log(err);
            res.render('index',{
            title: pages.title,
            content: pages.content
        });
    
    });
});
```

**and here i will show you my index from views**

```
<%- include ("./_layouts/header") %>

<%- content %>

<%- include ("./_layouts/footer") %>
```

[image: this my page collection]

**i dont now what can i do please help me thanks**

Answer (score 0):

`content` in your index.ejs needs to be marked as a variable.

This can be done by using the `=` sign in your file.

```html
<%= content %>
```

Comment: also i saw same error content is not defined :) thanks

Comment: You're welcome! If my answer helped can you mark it as accepted?